# Choosing the layout managers and number of panels for Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I would appreciate, If anyone here is kind enough to recommend me what are the layout managers to choose 
and how to separate the attached GUI into Jpanels.

[image]

Thanks so much in advance.

What I have tried so far:

Jframe - BorderLayout
Map (the grid and clear button from another class extending jpanel) - so I have put it in jframe.CENTER

the buttons to the right: jframe.EAST
I put them in a jpanel in a gridlayout (but I cannot get the spacing between the components)

buttons at the bottom: jframe.SOUTH
I put them in a jpanel in a gridlayout (but I cannot get the spacing between the components)

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @Rudy : Thanks for asking. and sorry didn't put it first. I edited the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When trying to determine what layout(s) you should use, you should start by trying to determine areas of responsibility...

For example...

[image]

Based on your needs, I might start with a `GridBagLayout`.  This might seem complex, but if you break the UI down into seperate components, focusing on their individual needs, it should become simpler...

For the panel on the left...

[image]

I would be temptered to use a `GridBagLayout`, simply because it allows the components to use there preferred sizes, but still allows you to set up a grid like pattern...

For the arrow buttons...

[image]

This becomes a little more complicated, but I would use a `GridLayout(2, 3)` (2 rows, 3 columns).  This will require to add a filler panel at the first and third position along the top row, but still maintain the buttons at a equal size...

For this panel...

[image]

I would be tempted to either use a `GridBagLayout`, because it will allow you to span the rows or even split it again into two separate panels, with the controls on the left in a `GridLayout(2, 1)` and the control on the right in something like a `BorderLayout` as required...

For "progress" panel...

[image]

I would be tempted to use...`GridBagLayout`.  Mostly because it would allow you to provide more weight to the progress bars then the labels.

For the main panel...

[image]

I would probably be tempted to either use a `BorderLayout`, with the `Clear Map` on another panel of it's own, allowing it maintain it's preferred size, in the `NORTH` position and the map panel in the `CENTER` or even a `GridBagLayout` depending on what the invidual components are...

Comment: This is great!!!! Thanks for taking time answering the question in such great detail. :)

Comment: I finally did it! [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/OBFegg0.jpg). Thanks again. Love GridBagLayout!