# Using many panesl in a class that extends JPanel

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe, jpanel

I have a main class which extends `JFrame`, and its content is contained in other classes which extend `JPanel`.

Now, in those other classes, I want to use several panels to group the content in a good order.

Is it possible to use many panels( by creating several `JPanel` objects in that class) in this class that extends `JPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` extends `JComponent`, which extends `Container`, so `JPanel` is a container, so it contain other `Component`.

So, yes, you can do this and in fact, depending on the context and requirements, is actually a good idea.

You could take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422871/which-java-swing-layout-should-i-use/15423217#15423217) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842607/choosing-the-layout-managers-and-number-of-panels-for-java-gui/18842921#18842921)

mKorbel makes a valid point.  It is generally not recommended to extend from top level containers like `JFrame`, instead, use something like `JPanel` as you primary application interface (adding other containers and components to it as you see fit) and adding this frame to an instance of `JFrame` which you create

Comment: Edit: the other classes extend JPanel, not JFrame

Comment: @GThuo That did have me worried ;)

Comment: This exactly is my problem:
Lets say I have this class `MainPage`
`public class MainPage extends JPanel {
public MainPage() {
 //create 2 buttons
JButton actAddUser = new JButton("Add User");
JButton actAddBook = new JButton("Add Book");
//add this buttons to this panel
add(actAddUser);
add(actAddBook);
//now create a text field
JTextField text = new JTextField();
//now i want to add this to a different panel
//something like
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.add(text);`
Is this allowable, because it is throwing an exception of adding window to container?

Comment: Yes it's allowed, some where in your class hierarchy, some is extending from a window based class

Comment: thank you. My problem is not sorted. On top of your suggestion, I stopped extending the classes with `JPanel`